# What is the error for intrinsic function !Ref in this Cloudformation template in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

Recently I have started exploring AWS CloudFormation in YAML format. I am getting error message:

> Encountered unsupported property Type

The description of the YAML code is as below:-

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Resources: 
  DevEC2Instance:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
    Properties:
      ImageId: ami-04aa88aebb9fefd83
      Type: t2.micro
      KeyName: Newkey
      SecurityGroups:
       - default
       - !Ref SSHSecurityGroup
SSHSecurityGroup:
  Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
  Properties:
    GroupDescription: Group_For_CloudFormation
    SecurityGroupIngress:
    - Ipprotocol: tcp
      FromPort: '22'
      ToPort: '22'
      CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
```

Comment: "Encountered unsupported property GroupDecsription" - what part is unclear about that? You have typo: `GroupDescription` != `GroupDecsription`.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-security-group.html

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if this snippet works for you?

```
Resources:

  DevEC2Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      ImageId: ami-04aa88aebb9fefd83
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      KeyName: Newkey
      SecurityGroups:
        - default
        - !Ref SSHSecurityGroup
  SSHSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Group_For_CloudFormation
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 22
          ToPort: 22
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
```

Answer (score 0):

So the Correct code is as below:-

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Resources: 
  DevEC2Instance:
   Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
   Properties:
     ImageId: ami-04aa88aebb9fefd83
     InstanceType: t2.micro
     KeyName: Newkey
     SecurityGroups:
      - default 
      - !Ref SSHSecurityGroup
  SSHSecurityGroup:
     Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
     Properties:
      GroupDescription: SMy Security Group
      SecurityGroupIngress:
       - IpProtocol: tcp
         FromPort: '22'
         ToPort: '22'
         CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
```

Answer (score 0):

The error's due to a missing **indentation** on the resource `SSHSecurityGroup`, in YAML you need to be careful with indentation. This makes that Cloudformation doesn't take the element as a Resource, cause it's on the same level of indentation.

This should work:

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Resources: 
  DevEC2Instance:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
    Properties:
      ImageId: ami-04aa88aebb9fefd83
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      KeyName: Newkey
      SecurityGroups:
       - default
       - !Ref SSHSecurityGroup
  SSHSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Group_For_CloudFormation
      SecurityGroupIngress:
       - IpProtocol: tcp
         FromPort: '22'
         ToPort: '22'
         CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
```

Comment: Type should be ImageType and it should be IpProtocol.

Comment: You're right about IpProtocol. For Type it should be InstanceType, ImageType doesn't appear in the official documentation for Ec2 Instance. Both have been corrected.